# Twitter: Get tweets for a particular time period

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I am new to Twitter APIs. I am implementing a module in Java which shows popularity of a #hashtag. So I have to collect tweets for regular time interval.

Is there a way to get all the tweets that contains particular #hashtag, so I can the count total tweets each time and get the popularity? Below URL give me tweets but it's not consistent. Doesn't give me all tweets.

`http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23example`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using urls use Api Twitter 4j

http://twitter4j.org/en/

You can perform this function eaisly with that

With Twitter4J, you can easily integrate your Java application with the Twitter service.

**But Twitter4J is an unofficial library.**

Use this function of that api

Search for Tweets

```
 // The factory instance is re-useable and thread safe.
    Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
    Query query = new Query("source:twitter4j yusukey");
    QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
    for (Status status : result.getStatuses()) {
        System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + ":" + status.getText());
    }
```

Check this url for snippets

http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html